# How many $7$-digit pin codes can be made if there are no repeats, and the digits $1, 3$, and $6$ must be present?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many $7$-digit pin codes can be made, if:
>
> - there are no repeats, and
> - the digits $1, 3$, and $6$ must be present?

I am having trouble with this question as my professor wrote conflicting answers on the board, and I am having trouble with combinatorics.

On the board, he wrote $7C3 \times (7!)$, but I don't understand why he put $7C3$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: So on the board he wrote 7C3 x (7!) but I dont understand why he put 7C3.

Comment: Does "no repeats" mean that no digit appears twice anywhere in the final number... or instead that no digit can be adjacent itself (e.g., $7114369$)?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  For an exercise such as this, you should include your own attempt at solving the problem and explain where you are stuck (in the question itself, not the comments) so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the set of numbers, $0...9,$ we need to choose and arrange a set of $7$ numbers. But $1, 3, \text{and } 6$ are already present so we have 7 numbers, and we must choose 4 for the remaining spaces, hence the $7C4.$
After choosing the $7$ numbers, there are $7!$ ways to arrange them to form distinct pins, which leads to the final answer of $7!\cdot$$7\choose{4}$

Regarding your uncertainty about $7C3$, recall that $7\choose{4}$ = $7\choose{3}$ as $n\choose{r}$ = $n\choose{n-r}$

Comment: Okay I see now, thank you